# Effect of earlier US B1 visa reject on F1 application

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, study

I had applied for US B1 visa through my employer. It was rejected. AFAIK, it is because of the intended duration of stay. The officer was not convinced and issued a reject. Reason: 214 (b). Now I will be applying for F1 student visa. Will there any impacts of this earlier reject and if so, how can it be countered?

Comment: A section 214 (b) refusal means that your application failed to overcome the presumption that you intend to immigrate to the US (see http://newdelhi.usembassy.gov/consular/refused-or-pending-visa/214b-refusal.html).  The intended duration of your stay may have played a part in the officer's thinking, but it should not have been the main reason for this rejection.  I don't know whether the evaluation of immigration intent is different for students, but I suspect it is.

Comment: http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/denials.html#214b

Comment: @CGCampbell Eh? B1 visas are perfectly suitable here.